# get data out of vector array loop for later use C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello so i wrote this code.. It asks how many diffrent type of items you have, then makes vector array based on that.. Then ask's how many items of each type you have, then asks price and it counts price * items.. So i need to get the price * items out from that loop for later use here's my code:

```
float products()
{
    cout << "How many diffrent products ? ";
    int nProducts;
    //Takes number of diffrent type products
    cin >> nProducts;
    //This is for the vector array it takes nProducts as parameter of how many items it has 
    vector<float> fCountPrice(nProducts);
    //This is just for to have diffrent number in each cout
    int x = 1;
    //this loop adds value for all items in array
    for (int i = 0; i < fCountPrice.size(); i++ & x++)
        {
        cout <<"How many of product  "<< x << " you have? ";
        cin >> fCountPrize[i];
        //This asks for price of each product so it can be multiplied
        cout << "Price of product ? ";
        float fPrice;
        cin >> fPrice;
        fCountPrice[i] = fPrice * fCountPrize[i];
        cout << fCountPrize[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

Now i got to figure out how to get data from fCountPrize to return it to the program.. This is just small part of the program. I need to get data from the fCountPrize array to use in the main() function.. I don't have any idea how to do that. I tried declaring it in header but when i try to cout it in main get error: invalid types 'float[int]' for array subscript

Comment: You're returning a single `float`. Perhaps you wanted to return a vector of them and return `fCountPrice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<float> products() //change return type
{
        cout << "How many diffrent products ? ";
        int nProducts;
        //Takes number of diffrent type products
        cin >> nProducts;
        //This is for the vector array it takes nProducts as parameter of how many items it has 
        vector<float> fCountPrice(nProducts);
        vector<float> fCountPrize(nProducts);
        //This is just for to have diffrent number in each cout
        int x = 1;
        //this loop adds value for all items in array
        for (int i = 0; i < fCountPrice.size(); i++, x++)
            {
            cout <<"How many of product  "<< x << " you have? ";
            cin >> fCountPrize[i];
            //This asks for price of each product so it can be multiplied
            cout << "Price of product ? ";
            float fPrice;
            cin >> fPrice;
            fCountPrice[i] = fPrice * fCountPrize[i];
            cout << fCountPrize[i] << endl;
            }
            return fCountPrice;
    }

int main(){
   vector<float> retVal;
   retVal=products();
   cout<<retVal[0];


}
```

Comment: Almost there.. now i get no match for 'operator=' in 'retVal=products()'

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Have you included relevant headers, specially #include<vector>

Comment: i have included <iostream> and <vector> in all of my files.. Do i maybe need something else?

Comment: @Pau-Lee I have updated the full program, copy it exactly and tell me what you get

Comment: @PauLee Is there supposed to be two different vectors, `fCountPrice` and `fCountPrize`? It's not clear from your original code, which uses both vectors but only declares one